# Saving part of function output to a file in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, save

I have a simple scraping function that gives back particular things from given urls.
It sends back dictionary from which I'd like to save things to a .md file in a certain way.
Code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_data(url):
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    iframe = []
    yt_secondary = []

    div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'tags'})
    for entry in div:
        tags = entry.text.strip().replace('#', '').split('\n')

    songs_links = soup.find_all('iframe')[0]
    iframe.append(songs_links)

    entry = {'tags': tags,
             'iframe': songs_links}
    return entry


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_data('https://nikisaku.tumblr.com/post/643205680992485376/test'))
```

and it gives back this, as intended:

```
{'tags': ['Tagged: testing, test2, test3, .'], 'iframe': <iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bwKfVwiUpvo?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" width="500"></iframe>}
```

Now I want to be able to save this to a .md file in a format of:

```
---
tags: Tagged: testing, test2, test3, .
---
<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bwKfVwiUpvo?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" width="500"></iframe>
```

Is this even possible to save it like that?
I need to have it as this function, because I'm going to use it to go through X of given pages to scrape for tags and links (that works) and for every result I have to create a new .md file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function returns dictionary, you can loop through it and print keys, values separately:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_data = get_data('https://nikisaku.tumblr.com/post/643205680992485376/test')

    for key, value in raw_data.items():
        if type(value) is list:
            print(f"---\n{key}: {', '.join(value)}")
        else:
            print(f"---\n{key}: {value}")
```

Result would look like this:

```
---
tags: Tagged: testing, test2, test3, .
---
iframe: <iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" ...
```